# select odd with several tables on the site?

Tags: jquery

**EDIT**
Hi. I got 1 page(html) where I got a couple of tables. I want so within each table every odd row got a class. My problem is it only take the first table and go on with the odd on to the others to, when it just suppose to do that with in that one table, stop, start over with the next table. like this table, every other row, add class, next table, every other row, add class. NOW it's like table, every other row for all the tables. U know?

**EDIT**
Reason I want it to go into each table is because this is a menu and each menu got this structure.

table
1:st tr, title
2:nd tr, menu
3:rd tr, menu 
and so on

If I just do a tr:odd it will just keep going with addClass and on the next table it will mess up my title, you know?

I tried two different ways both wont work the way I would like them to. regular and each

```
$.each( {'.tableMenu'}, function () {
            $('table.tableMenu tr:odd').addClass('tableSubMenu');
});


$('table.tableMenu tr:odd').addClass('tableSubMenu');
```

Comment: I'm confused... on what you are trying to achieved..

Comment: I don't get why you don't just do 

    $('tr:odd').addClass('tableSubMenu');

if you just need to add this class to all odd tr of all your tables? I think you need to clarify your issue as said before ^^

Comment: Because then it will just keep going with the addClass every other tr. I want it to go to one specific table and start there, look at my edit

Comment: if you want on a specific, do it with id not by class

Comment: Yea I know ID but I want it to go to all the tables? I got like X amount of tables depending on how many menu titles there are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add each loop.

```
$('table.tableMenu').each(function(){
    $(this).find("tr:odd").addClass('tableSubMenu');
});
```

See working demo http://www.jsfiddle.net/MpQth/

Comment: for the love of God!... finally someone underst00d the OP! +1

Comment: Thanks that was just what I was looking for. I tried the each, don't know what I was missing in mine? maybe it was that I had table.tableMenu in there aswell? anyway thanks again